# Apache does not start at boot up because of socket binding error but starts manually

Tags: linux, apache, centos

Apache server is giving  an error at boot up (or when I try to start the service with `systemctl` manually)

> make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:7301    # virtual host port

But it starts nicely with following command:

> httpd -k start

Comment: What user are you using for both actions?  Ex. if you call systemctl as a regular user and httpd as root, results will be different.

Comment: Apache can only be start as root. It is just 'systemctl' which is causing trouble (server as service).

Answer (score 0):

3 things come to mind:

1. That port, 7301 is already in use by another process, try a `netstat -apn | grep 7301` to see if that's the case and if so change the apache port or kill that process.
2. You have 2 conflicting `Listen` directives in your apache conf file. For ex. `Listen *:7301` and `Listen 1.2.3.4:7301` would cause that error, pleasr remove one of them
3. You have configured apache to use an interface which is not active or does not have IPv6 enabled

Edit:

4. You have selinux active on your host and it's preventing apache from using a non default port as port 80.

Comment: But server should not be started manually because of these conflicts.